# Underline heading - narrower line

Tags: css, line, underline, heading

I want to create something like this.
[image]

I'm realy tired, cuz i can create only line with similar width like heading. I have to create "smaller" line then heading. Tried done it with ::before, but it doesn't work for me. Is there any possible way to create it.

```
<h1>Some heading here</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53zxor2k/

Comment: Why not ask why your `::before` styling isn't working (and post that code here)? That or `::after` are viable ways to do it.

Comment: did you give your `:before` the `content:' ';` rule?

Comment: It does not look like underline at all. Please describe what you actually want, show your best effort (HTML and CSS in the question itself), and specify how it fails to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 70%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Change the width to how long you would like it to be, and the "left" to where the line is located, and increase the "margin-top" to make it farther away from the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/53zxor2k/1/

Comment: `left` should be 15px, or `(100 - width) / 2`

Comment: The problem with making the heading an `inline-block` is that it no longer behaves as expected. Easy to demo by adding a paragraph after the heading: http://jsfiddle.net/6v4mjcaq/

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 { 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center
}

h1:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -6px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    transform:translateX(-65px) /*    width/2    */
}
```

```html
<h1>some heading here</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>some <span style="border-bottom: 2px solid red;">heading</span> here</h1>
```

You can simply put a border under a specific word if that is what you are attempting to do.